# 3-D Design Software

Tags: windows, 3d, graphic-design

I am a graphic designer, who has for the majority of my career worked with Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop (Among other members of the Adobe Suite). Recently I have taken an interest in 3-D Design, creating text in perspective or a street corner for example, all using the perspective grid included in Adobe Illustrator. More recently I've taken on more complex 3-D Designs, such as ones that would require more than one perspective grid, multiple layers and extrusions, etc. Illustrator is generally meant for 2-D Design, which is where I am stuck.

The first thing that comes to mind is a program like AutoCad or the simpler google sketchup, but is this really the best route? I would like to export 3-D models as vectors from a fixed position (like a snapshot) or at the very least a high quality render as an  image file. Any recommendations are appreciated.

tl;dr
I'm looking for some software to make complex 3-D models, for the purpose of interesting 3-D designs, preferably to export as vectors or high quality images, because Adobe illustrator doesn't handle complex models very well..

Comment: Have you tried https://www.blender.org ?

Comment: @Tob I have worked with blender in the past, I thought it was reserved for animations, but I guess if I exported one "frame" as the image I am looking for..

Comment: @RyanWeaver why not "indicate" if you like (or dislike) Tob's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Blender](https://www.blender.org) might be the tool you are looking for. See the [render output options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/output.html) on how to save a single frame as an image.